# CSS overflow scroll (bootstrap)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to "stretch" or expand Section A in Column 1 to fill the height of the row.

1 row, 2 columns:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|      Column 1       |      Column 2       |
|                     |                     |
| +-----------------+ | +-----------------+ |
| |      Button     | | | Section B       | |
| +-----------------+ | | Expand/collapse | |
|                     | +-----------------+ |
| +-----------------+ |                     |
| | Section A       | | +-----------------+ |
| |                 | | | Section C       | |
| | Expands to      | | |                 | |
| | height of 2nd   | | |                 | |
| | Column 2,       | | |                 | |
| | inner contents  | | |                 | |
| | scroll          | | |                 | |
+ +-----------------+ | +-----------------+ | 
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

"Button" generates text into Section A.

Section A's should expand to fill height and the overflow should be scrollable.

Section B is a collapsible panel.

Section C is also generated.

The height of Column 2 should "drive" the height of Column 1.

A fiddle is worth 1,000 words so: https://jsfiddle.net/gnp47bLf/3/

I've tried setting the height to 100%, but that doesn't work.  Click on the generate button to dynamically load some text.  I'm not sure if CSS flex property is the way to go or how to use. Bootstrap4 latest beta being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`flexbox utility`](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) classes are your friends in these situations.

To achieve the desired layout, the `.tab-pane` and `.results-wrapper` have to stretch till the bottom of the main row.
So to get there, `.d-flex` was added to `.card-body` and `.h-100` to `.tab-pane`. Then, in order to give the ability to the `.results-wrapper` to also reach the bottom of the row, `.d-flex .flex-column` was also applied on `.tab-pane`. In the meantime `.results-wrapper` was moved to be a direct child of `.tab-pane` as well.

```js
$().ready(function() {
    $('#generate').click(function() {
        html = '<ul>';
        for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            html += `<li>${i}</li>`;
        }
        html += '</ul>'
        $('#myText').html(html);
    })
});
```

```css
.results-wrapper {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row border border-warn">

        <div class="col border border-success">
            <div class="card text-center h-100">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">TAB A</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">TAB B</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body d-flex">
                    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">

                        <div class="tab-pane h-100 fade show active d-flex flex-column" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="generate">Generate</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                I would like the grey area to stretch vertically based upon the row's overall height, but without hardcoding the height to a set pixel value.  Click the "Information" link to expand more data.
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col results-wrapper">
                                <div class="col-12 results bg-secondary" id="myText">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
                            Hi
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col border border-info">
            <div class="row" id="divItemInfo">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                            <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span id="div_current_item_information_header">Information</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-body collapse" id="collapseExample">
                            <div id="div_current_item_information_body">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut nisl non risus venenatis finibus sed at dolor. Mauris aliquam libero nisl, condimentum ullamcorper turpis dignissim sed. Integer maximus a quam eu semper. Cras id enim non lorem ornare varius id et lacus. Ut molestie massa eu felis gravida tristique sit amet sed nisi. Maecenas id velit tortor. Suspendisse euismod rhoncus lectus cursus finibus. Praesent vestibulum scelerisque laoreet. Mauris vulputate semper nibh ac facilisis.                                       
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut nisl non risus venenatis finibus sed at dolor. Mauris aliquam libero nisl, condimentum ullamcorper turpis dignissim sed. Integer maximus a quam eu semper. Cras id enim non lorem ornare varius id et lacus. Ut molestie massa eu felis gravida tristique sit amet sed nisi. Maecenas id velit tortor. Suspendisse euismod rhoncus lectus cursus finibus. Praesent vestibulum scelerisque laoreet. Mauris vulputate semper nibh ac facilisis.
                    <br/><br/>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut nisl non risus venenatis finibus sed at dolor. Mauris aliquam libero nisl, condimentum ullamcorper turpis dignissim sed. Integer maximus a quam eu semper. Cras id enim non lorem ornare varius id et lacus. Ut molestie massa eu felis gravida tristique sit amet sed nisi. Maecenas id velit tortor. Suspendisse euismod rhoncus lectus cursus finibus. Praesent vestibulum scelerisque laoreet. Mauris vulputate semper nibh ac facilisis.
                    <br/><br/>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut nisl non risus venenatis finibus sed at dolor. Mauris aliquam libero nisl, condimentum ullamcorper turpis dignissim sed. Integer maximus a quam eu semper. Cras id enim non lorem ornare varius id et lacus. Ut molestie massa eu felis gravida tristique sit amet sed nisi. Maecenas id velit tortor. Suspendisse euismod rhoncus lectus cursus finibus. Praesent vestibulum scelerisque laoreet. Mauris vulputate semper nibh ac facilisis.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row border border-primary">
        <div class="col">
            Another Column
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't really a Bootstrap question. You have a fixed height on `.results-wrapper`. Try removing `height: 100px;` from that class and it should work OK.

When it comes to Bootstrap, there's a class `h-100` that can be used to make a column height 100%. However, that isn't relevant in this case here.

Comment: If height: 100px is removed, it expands the row. But I don't want all of the grey box to appear.  I want it to be scrollable.  It shouldn't be larger than the contents of the second column.  https://jsfiddle.net/4mL0Ldnj/